# Convert strings to factors with levels, but warn when introducing NAs

Tags: r, r-factor

I'm preparing an old dataset for analysis, and need to convert strings to factors, using levels. I've used a (equally old) data dictionary to set the levels, but have just noticed that it's not entirely correct -- some strings in some variables are not in the data dictionary.

I'd like to prevent strings being dropped (converted to NA) without warning--ideally I'd like things to stop completely if a string is not in the level definition. Is that possible?

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = letters[1:3])
factor(df$c1, levels = letters[1:2])
# [1] a    b    <NA>
```

Happy to use `dplyr`, `forcats` or something else.

Comment: "I'd like things to stop completely" - it sounds as though what you want is a function to check whether all of the character variables in one vector are found in a second vector of character variables (the levels) - if so convert to factor, if not don't and report which are missing?

Comment: See `?setdiff` to compare between two vectors.

Comment: You're probably right, a separate function / check is needed.